# Is there a way to implement constraints in Haskell's type classes?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, class, constraints, typeclass

Is there some way (*any* way) to implement constraints in type classes?

As an example of what I'm talking about, suppose I want to implement a Group as a type class. So a type would be a group if there are three functions:

```
class Group a where
    product :: a -> a -> a  
    inverse :: a -> a 
    identity :: a
```

But those are not any functions, but they must be related by some constraints. For example:

```
product a identity = a 
product a (inverse a) = identity
inverse identity = identity
```

etc...

Is there a way to enforce this kind of constraint in the definition of the class so that any instance would automatically inherit it? As an example, suppose I'd like to implement the C2 group, defined by:

```
 data C2 = E | C 

 instance Group C2 where
      identity = E 
      inverse C = C
```

This two definitions uniquely determines C2 (the constraints above define all possible operations - in fact, C2 is the only possible group with two elements because of the constraints). Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: (Er, `inverse C = C`, surely?)

Comment: Those constraints are usually called *laws* example , Monad laws.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there a way to enforce this kind of constraint?

**No.**  *Lots* of people have been asking for it, including the illustrious Tony Hoare, but nothing appears on the horizon yet.

This problem would be an excellent topic of discussion for the [Haskell Prime](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/) group.  If anyone has floated a good proposal, it is probably to be found there.

P.S. This is an important problem!

Comment: I have the firm belief that compile-time checking for satisfaction of such constraints is halting-equivalent. Can you shed some light on this matter?

Comment: @fishlips: I'd be shocked if a compiler could check all by itself whether an implementation satisfies such constraints, but I can't claim to know the term-rewriting literature well enough to be confident of writing a proof.  However I suspect that in any likely deployment, if a programmer wants constraints checked at *compile* time, he or she will be required to supply a machine-checkable proof!

Comment: hummm... that's sad to hear. 

Is there any other language which can perform this kind of constraint checking?

One problem I would like to solve is exactly to make a program that finds all possible instances given some algebraic constraints like in this case (i.e., find all possible order n groups). 

I heard prolog can do something like that, but I'd rather have a functional language.

Comment: @Rafael S. Calsaverini: Languages that support dependent types can verify such properties, but you will have to provide the constructive proofs about the constraint satisfaction.

The Agda2 language is very similar to Haskell and has many nice tutorials so you'll get started pretty quickly. You may wish to take a look at Epigram too.

Answer (score 8):

In some cases you can specify the properties using QuickCheck.  This is not exactly enforcement, but it lets you provide generic tests that all instances should pass.  For instance with Eq you might say:

```
prop_EqNeq x y = (x == y) == not (x != y)
```

Of course it is still up to the instance author to call this test.

Doing this for the monad laws would be interesting.

Answer (score 5):

Type classes can contain definitions as well as declarations. Example:

```
class Equality a where
    (?=), (!=) :: a -> a -> Bool

    a ?= b = not (a != b)
    a != b = not (a ?= b)

instance Eq a => Equality a where
    (?=) = (==)

test = (1 != 2)
```

You can also specify special constraints (let's call them *laws*) in plain Haskell, but it's not guaranteed that the compiler will use them. A common example are [monadic laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_Laws)